# How to manage flyway migration across multiple apps sharing same database

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, flyway

How to manage flyway migration across multiple apps sharing same database.

1. Service-A based on Spring Boot, points to Database-A
2. Service-B based on Spring Boot, points to Database-A
3. Service-C based on Spring Boot, points to Database-A

How should we manage flyway migration scripts

1. Should we have a separate repository for managing the database scripts
2. Since each of the services are launched as docker containers and we don't want the migration to be triggered on each of the container
3. What would be the preferred way to manage the flyway migration scripts, so that it allows us to rollback or promote changes in a CI/CD environment

Comment: Are all your services pointing at the same schema within the database?

Comment: What would the downside be of the migration being triggered on each container given that Flyway only runs versioned scripts that haven't been run against the target?

Comment: @Barry yes same schema within the database

Comment: @DavidAtkinson I don't want each container to run the flyway scripts

Comment: @Rpj Do you have some pic / flow of the current state and newly required state? I am not sure what is migrated, all services from db A to a newly db B?

Comment: Flyway updates it's own table to indicate which files already have run. It will skip already run files. So @DavidAtkinson is right, the is no problem, but you have to ensure that only one service is doing the migration before running the others. So you should start one service in a new version so it runs flyway, and when it finishes start the others. Other option is to create a docker image (for instance) that only runs flyway and updates the database accordingly. In practice extract the database files to another project and run migration only in this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a module containing all migration scripts, which can be added as a dependency by all services (A, B and C in your example). Once you have that in place, only one of the services should run the migrations e.g, service A and the other services (B and C) should just validate the schema. As an advantage, if you are running integration tests on your services, they can run flyway independently at test time or on your CI/CD pipeline to execute the test. Even for local development, Flyway can be activated.

Unfortunately, this introduces a slight dependency on the deployment order of your services, they can still be deployed in any order, but till the service in charge of the migration's executions does its job, the other will be unhealthy. If you use some kind of Blue/Green deployment style, silos or similar, this should not be a problem, but just something to consider.

If you decided to try something like that, you just need to overwrite the Flyway migration phase and leave the migration method empty while the validation still operative. I think you need to look at `FlywayMigrationStrategy`, but I haven't done it in some time, check yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

There is arguably nothing stopping you from doing this.
If all three services are using different schemas on the same database instance, you can set the `defaultSchema` and `schemas` properties for each services flyway configuration to insure the schema history table is within each services respective schema and there wont be any overlap.

However, if your are using the same schemas for each service, I've seen in previous projects that versioning can trip systems up.

**For example:**
If each service manages its own migration script versions, this can cause conflicts. I.E. If service A has a V1, V2 and V3 script and so does service B then flyway will throw a checksum error as it will detect the content of V1 etc has changed when migrating service B after service A.
However, this can be over come with careful versioning of your migration scripts. For ease I'd suggest using a versioning system which implicitly creates a temporal order, for example `V2022.08.26.10.01__your_script.sql`.

Alternatively, you could use the [out of order](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/outOfOrder) as well to keep better control of your migration order

Comment: All services are using the same schema

Comment: Are you suggesting you have the relevant migration scripts in each microservice. This causes confusion, since there are dependencies between services and their schemas present in multiple repositories. This makes it hard to write test cases as well

Comment: Would prefer having a separate repo for managing all the database migrations, not sure if how other projects handle this complexity

Answer (score 0):

**As a solution:**
You can customize Flyway history table name for each service so that you can avoid validation exceptions that are mentioned above.

**Side Effects:**
Theoretically using same DB schema is considered as anti-pattern, but practically you may need it during service separation as an initial phase.

You may need find proper solution some maintenance problems like:

- multiple ownership of DB tables: you need better integration tests to avoid breaking other services while changing common tables
- You need to order deployment for separate services